# How to make an element not trigger scrollbars?

Tags: html, css

I have a page of fixed height, 661px, the height of Safari on the iPad in landscape mode. On the iPad, I don't want it to scroll; the content should exactly fit.

On a taller browser window, however, I want some extra content (a copyright line) to show beneath the 661px fold. But again, no scrollbar should appear until the window is less than 661px tall, i.e. the footer should be clipped off before the scrollbar appears.

```
+--------+    +--------+    +--------+ ^
|        |    |        |    |        | #
|        |    |        |    |        | v
+--------+    +--------+
  Footer 

   (1)           (2)           (3)
```

1. Window taller than 661px; no scrollbar
2. Window exactly 661px; footer is clipped, but still no scrollbar
3. Window less than 661px; scrollbar appears

My simplified markup is as follows:

```
<body>
  <div class="all">
    ... main content ...
    <div class="footer">Copyright!</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
.all {
  height: 661px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 661px;
}
```

This puts all the elements in the right place, but somehow the footer still contributes to the page height and thus triggers a scrollbar, even though it sits inside an element whose height is less. No combination of `overflow` and `height` on `html`, `body` and `.all` seems to fix this, neither in Chrome nor in Firefox.

What's the correct way to do this?

And I'd also like to ask the more general question: how are scrollbars on the window triggered? Apparently it's not simply if the height of the `body` is larger than the window, as the Chrome inspector shows that both `html` and `body` have the expected 661px height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a conditional stylesheet? Add the following tag

```
media="screen AND (max-height:661px)"
```

to a stylesheet and it will only apply to screen viewing where the maximum height of the browser window is 661px, which will by your calculations include the iPad but nothing bigger. You could then in this sheet make your copyright information `display:none` to remove it from the document flow.

---

Just saw your edit. You should be able to use the height property for the media attribute to do what you want. I am assuming that your content will be sized down to the pixel to fit on a 661px tall screen, so all you really have to do is insert the copyright information for any screens which are taller. Smaller screens will have scrollbars automatically, and the 661px iPad screen should fit just right.

I can't test this out, so I'd appreciate it if you tell me how it works (or doesn't) :)

Comment: Perfect! To err on the safe side, I set `max-height: 700px`. This makes the footer appear only if all of it fits. Still open to alternative answers not involving media queries, but this is quite elegant really.

Comment: I just learned about this a few days ago :D. So glad I could help!

Comment: @Thomas: This is an example of Responsive Design, for which media queries are the appropriate solution. Any other solution would be far less elegant.

Comment: Agreed. Just wondering about my more general question "where does the scrollbar come from?".